# How to add and merge custom view into appcompat toolbar?

Tags: android, android-custom-view, toolbar, android-appcompat

[image]

I want to implement a search view by adding a EditText to toolbar.
Here is my layout,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:background="@android:color/white"
              android:clickable="true"
              android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/search_input"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:hint="search"/>

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/place_holder"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"></FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

, and my activity extends from ActionBarActivity.

As Google documented

> One or more custom views. The application may add arbitrary child
>   views to the Toolbar. They will appear at this position within the
>   layout. If a child view's Toolbar.LayoutParams indicates a Gravity
>   value of CENTER_HORIZONTAL the view will attempt to center within the
>   available space remaining in the Toolbar after all other elements have
>   been measured.

I set the layout_gravity of EditText as `center_horizontal`. But it turns out that the EditText flows to the next row.

Is it possible to float the textedit to the right of the arrow icon?

Comment: Why not use SearvhView? http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html

Comment: Yes, SearchView is a solution. But I want to replace the EditText with a custom one to provide some interesting feature. I think Toolbar is better at  layout than ActionBar, maybe I can add an EditText inside. As far as I know, some guys put TextView or ImageView into the toolbar. See http://www.101apps.co.za/index.php/articles/using-toolbars-in-your-apps.html